# Running a binary using makefile

Tags: makefile

From all targets I have, I need one to `run` the program.

From command line, I would state:

```
$ make main_run.err
```

or

```
$ make main_time.err
```

If it was specific to a certain program, I would write the rule:

```
main_run.err main_time.err: main.x
    @echo ------------------- $(DEFSYM) Running ---------------------
    /usr/bin/time -p -o main_time.err ./main.x > main_run.err || true
    @echo -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, how to generalize it?

My first attempt was:

Command line:

```
$ make run main.x
```

And the rule:

```
run: $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
    @echo --------------- $(DEFSYM) Running -----------------
    /usr/bin/time -p -o time.err ./$< > run.err || true
    @echo ---------------------------------------------------
```

This gave me some strange errors:

```
make: Circular run <- run dependency dropped.
------------- BUILD_150729_162018 Running -----------------
/usr/bin/time -p -o time.err ./main.x > run.err || true
-----------------------------------------------------------
make: 'main.x' is up to date.
```

My second and best attempt, the one I'm asking for help (unless there is another really easier way), is:

```
%_run.err %_time.err: %.x
    @echo ------------------- $(DEFSYM) Running ---------------------
    /usr/bin/time -p -o $@_time.err ./$< > $@_run.err || true
    @echo -----------------------------------------------------------
```

This is almost ok! But filenames are wrong:

```
--------------- BUILD_150729_162239 Running -----------------
/usr/bin/time -p -o main_run.err_time.err ./main.x > main_run.err_run.err || true
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the command line is not good:

```
$ make main_run.err
```

I know I could use:

```
$ make run x=main
```

And define a variable `$(x)`, but I prefer:

```
$ make run main.x
```

if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attempt:

```
%_run.err %_time.err: %.x
    @echo ------------------- $(DEFSYM) Running ---------------------
    /usr/bin/time -p -o $@_time.err ./$< > $@_run.err || true
    @echo -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Is exactly the right idea. You just need to adjust the [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) you are using to match the change to a pattern rule.

Specifically you want the `$*` (stem) variable instead of the `$@` (target) variable.

From the manual:

> $@
>
> The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an archive member, then ‘$@’ is the name of the archive file. In a pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern Rules), ‘$@’ is the name of whichever target caused the rule’s recipe to be run.
>
> $*
>
> The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match). If the target is dir/a.foo.b and the target pattern is a.%.b then the stem is dir/foo. The stem is useful for constructing names of related files.
>
> In a static pattern rule, the stem is part of the file name that matched the ‘%’ in the target pattern.

So you end up with:

```
%_run.err %_time.err: %.x
    @echo ------------------- $(DEFSYM) Running ---------------------
    /usr/bin/time -p -o $*_time.err ./$< > $*_run.err || true
    @echo -----------------------------------------------------------
```

The original original:

```
main_run.err main_time.err: main.x
    @echo ------------------- $(DEFSYM) Running ---------------------
    /usr/bin/time -p -o main_time.err ./main.x > main_run.err || true
    @echo -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Was incorrect because it did **not** tell make that both files were created by a single run of the target so make might have run it twice if you specified *both* `main_run.err` and `main_time.err` at the same time. The pattern rule version **does** tell make about that fact (see the last paragraph of the manual section on [Pattern Rule Examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) for an explanation of that).

To make the initial command line a bit prettier you could add:

```
.PHONY: run_%
run_%: %_run.err %_time.err
```

Which will let you run `make run_main`.

...

I say that but in a quick mock-up test that doesn't work and it needs to be:

```
.PHONY: run_%
run_%: %_run.err %_time.err ;
```

instead but I'm not at all sure why offhand.

Comment: So I should run with `make main_run.err`? No way to just run with `make run main` or `make run main.x`?

Comment: Yes, this still uses `make main_run.err` *or* `make main_time.err` *or* `make main_run.err main_time.err`. You could add `.PHONY: run_%` and `run_%: %_run.err %_time.err` and then use `make run_main` if you wanted but no you can't use `make run main` unfortunately.

Comment: Perfect, @Etan. Thanks! (May I suggest you add this comment as part of the answer? Its perfect for what I've asked.)

Comment: Funny thing. Withough the semicolon it says `make: *** No rule to make target 'run_main'.  Stop.`

Comment: Right. It fails to chain the prerequisites correctly and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Also, for the record, I need `.PRECIOUS: %.o %_run.err %_time.err`. Without it, files `*.err` are deleted as temporary.

Comment: That's probably a side-effect of whatever is causing the empty target to be necessary.

Comment: Test case: instead of a semicolon, it also works with a single `TAB` in the begin of the new next line (an empty command line).

Comment: Yeah, the trailing semicolon and a blank line with a leading tab are identical. The semicolon is just clearer. See [Using Empty Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Recipes).